# Codeigniter form post url not reaching routes.php

Tags: codeigniter

One of my forms with a POST method is doing something weird. When I submit the form it sends the form url to the browser URL box and it doesn't hit the controller. What is causing this? I'm getting this only for one of my form and I've double checked and triple checked my routes.php file, my controller, etc.

Comment: It'll be better or a lot easier to fix your issue if you post your codes here. Please provide some snippet.

Comment: explore your question.! model controller and view.

Comment: To be aware what is the couse of that unpredictable behavior, you should post code from `.htaccess`, view, controller meant in form action, routes and probably `base_url()` value for start.